# cloaking a folder to show root with wordpress pretty permalinks with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I installed wordpress in a subdirectory, lets say www.example.com/wordpress. I want the user to hit www.example.com and see the index of www.example.com/wordpress. I'm already using a custom pretty permalinks structure /%category%/%pagename%/ so the htaccess file is a little foreign to me.

My current htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
```

I've tried numerous solutions from browsing across the web but nothing seems to work. I either get internal 500 errors or view previous pages in the root directory like example.com/about (even though I've deleted the original about.html in the root) even after I deleted my cache.

Any help you could give would be extremely helpful. Thanks for your time,
Rob

Comment: error 500? what sais your webserver error log? do you have proper AllowOverride permissios set in your webserver config?

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess file needs to be located in / and not in /wordpress/ and RewriteBase should be / not /wordpress/. Leave the permalinks setup on, but don't use an .htaccess file in /wordpress/. You'll need to set the root directory in your wordpress install to / and setup redirects for /wordpress/wp-content/ and the other wordpress subdirs in /.htaccess so that requests to those directories are also forwarded correctly.

I assume that you want to set up wordpress this way because there are other directories not associated with the wordpress install that you want to be accessible from / (www.example.com/cgi-bin/ for example). You'll need to set up your .htaccess file in / to make any directory aliases (like /cgi-bin/) accessible so requests to /cgi-bin/ don't get redirected to wordpress.

EDIT:
I haven't done something like this in a long time, but here's my best guess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule  ^wp-content/(.*)$  /wordpress/wp-content/$1  [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule  ^wp-admin/(.*)$  /wordpress/wp-admin/$1  [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule  ^wp-include/(.*)$  /wordpress/wp-include/$1  [L,QSA]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/yourAliasUnrelatedToWordpress [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I'm going to give this the old college try right now. I will let you know how it goes. Thank you so much for the quick response — it's highly appreciated.

Comment: Any chance you can help me out with writing the redirects for /wordpress/wp-content/ and the other wordpress subdirs in /.htaccess?